# What is the preferred way of putting and if condition in a try catch block?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, ng-bootstrap

I have a toast manager try catch block and it works as I expect it

```
showToast(status: string, message: string) {
try {
  if (status === 'success') {
    this.toastr.showSuccessToast(message)
  }
  else if (status === 'warning'){
    this.toastr.showWarningToast(message)
  }
  else {
    this.toastr.showErrorToast(message)
  }
} catch {
  console.log('Toast failed');
}
```

It seems to me this maybe inefficent but i don't know if I should remove the try catch or the if condition

Comment: Do you expect any of those functions to throw an error? Why do you think the code is inefficient?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with it. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: I was thinking this should be organized  outside of the try catch.. like a function inside try...

Comment: Why do you think this? (not saying it's wrong, just curious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for 2 changes here:

1. use `switch` instead of `if else`. easier to read and maintain.
2. Remove the `try catch` block. The only exceptions this block could catch could be raised by the `showSuccessToast`, `showWarningToast`, and `showErrorToast` of the `toastr`. I suppose `toastr` is a service provided by the ng-bootstrap. If you don't trust such a third-party service you would need to catch errors in many places. Instead, I would consider avoiding polluting the code with the `try catch` by [handling such exceptions at some global level](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler).